# How to use ISO-8859-1 encoding

Tags: ruby, shoes

I'm Portuguese and I'm having some troubles when trying to use Shoes Framework with words like "Não", "José" etc.

Here's an example:

```
 Shoes.app {
    stack {
      button "Jogar"
      button "Instruções"
      button "Créditos"
    }
  }
```

When I try to open this code on SHOES, it gives me a lot of errors like:

```
Invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
```

So I want to know how to change the encoding of shoes to use the ISO-8859-1 enconding.
PS: I've already tried to change the encoding on my .rb fileproject but it doesn't work.
I'm using Geany and Lubuntu.

Thank you!
Tiago Galvão

Comment: What version of ruby?

Comment: Version 2.2.0 and the SHOES 3.2 version for linux

Comment: And you have added `#encoding: ISO-8859-1` at the top of all your source files? Then shoes 4 probably just isn't compatible with that encoding.

Comment: I've edited my comment, i'm using shoes 3.2 ... sorry

Comment: That might be your problem. If you use UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1, does the error still happen? I think you might just have to either try shoes 4, or use UTF-8.

Comment: Adrian, thank you for your help! I've changed to UTF-8 and the error have persisted. However, I've tried the option "No Encoding" and the problem was solved.